# foreach Insert arrays as columns

Tags: php

I have four arrays:

```
$qtys = $_POST['qty'];
$colours = $_POST['colour'];
$sizes = $_POST['size'];
$names = $_POST['name'];
```

I want these to go into a mysql table like so:

```
qty      | colour     | size     | name
-------------------------------------------
$qtys[0] | $colour[0] | $size[0] | $name[0]
$qtys[1] | $colour[1] | $size[1] | $name[1]
```

I've tried various things, including this:

```
foreach($qtys as $value) {
  $i = 0;
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (qty,colour,size,name) VALUES ('$qtys[$i]','$colours[$i]','$sizes[$i]','$names[$i]')");
  $i++;
}
```

...but to no avail. Can anyone suggest a different `INSERT` statement that will get the data in the table? Do I need to iterate in the loop? I'm sure `$qtys as $value` is incorrect but have tried so many things with no luck.

Comment: Try again with `$i = 0;` *before* the `foreach`, otherwise `$i` will always be zero.

Comment: You should start with simply checking if your code does what you think it does ... that's probably most helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, whoever it was. Obviously unclear, not useful with no research effort. Thanks.

Comment: @bfavaretto good point, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use for loop will be ok, **AND REMEMBER ESCAPE USER INPUT**.

```
for($i =0, $count = count($qtys); $i < $count; $i++) {
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (qty,colour,size,name) VALUES ('$qtys[$i]','$colours[$i]','$sizes[$i]','$names[$i]')");
}
```

Comment: Spot on, thank you. I know all about escaping user input, it shall be done once I've got it working.

Comment: Make sure that the arrays are of the same length, otherwise you are going to run into a index out of bounds problem sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are resetting the counter each iteration, put `$i = 0` outside of the loop if you want to do it this way.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($qtys as $value) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (qty,colour,size,name) VALUES ('$qtys[$i]','$colours[$i]','$sizes[$i]','$names[$i]')");
    $i++;
}
```

A better (cleaner) way would be something like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $qtys.count(); $i++) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (qty,colour,size,name) VALUES ('$qtys[$i]','$colours[$i]','$sizes[$i]','$names[$i]')");
}
```

Also, are you sure that the arrays are always the same length? Otherwise you risk getting a index out of bounds problem..

Comment: Thanks. They are always the same length, yes, it will be validated prior to execution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (qty,colour,size,name) VALUES ";

$inserts = array();
for($i=0 ; $i < count($qtys); $i++) {
  $inserts[] = "('$qtys[$i]','$colours[$i]','$sizes[$i]','$names[$i]')";
} 

$sql .= implode(',', $inserts);
mysql_query($sql);
```

No need to run query again and again.